# Make background color lighter dynamically

Tags: wpf

I have a stackpanel with a wrappanel.

When the user hovers over the wrappanel I want the background to be a bit lighter than the current background, so it is clear for the user that he can click it.

The background is bound by my viewmodel and can change.

I use a Converter to convert an enum to a certain color.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="UserCallAlarmPanel" >
    <StackPanel.Resources>
         <Style x:Key="AlarmStyle" TargetType="{x:Type WrapPanel}">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=AlarmPanel}" Value="True" >
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding CallStatus, Converter={StaticResource CallStatusBackgroundConverter}}"/>
                     <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="20"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <WrapPanel Name="AlarmPanel" Height="25" MouseLeftButtonDown="AlarmPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown" Style="{StaticResource AlarmStyle}">
        <Viewbox> 
            <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource alarm_icon}"/>
        </Viewbox
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I tried to change to opacity but that doesn't work.

Comment: The valid values for `Opacity` are between 0 (fully transparent) and 1 (fully opaque).  If you want 20% opacity, you need to use 0.2 for the value.

Comment: Oh ok, that was the problem indeed. Stupid..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The valid values for `Opacity` are between 0 (fully transparent) and 1 (fully opaque). If you want 20% opacity, you need to use 0.2 for the value.